# I get "mysqli_query(): Empty query" error and can't find the wrong line

Tags: php, database, mysqli, upload

Hey Guys I run into a funny problem. I used this code for my other sites witch are working well. Now I just change the variables etc. and I get Empty Query error. I checked my code from line to line but did't find anything wrong.

I appreciate any help :)

Here is the code:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Insert New Product</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="index.php?insert_product" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="form_table">

      <tr>
        <td class="valign">Title:</td>
        <td class=""><input type="text" name="product_title" required></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="valign">Price:</td>
        <td class=""><input type="text" name="product_price" required></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="valign">Category:</td>
        <td class="">
          <select name="product_cat" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
              <?php getCats_select(); ?>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="valign">Brand:</td>
        <td class="">
          <select name="product_brand" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
              <?php getBrands_select(); ?>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="valign">Keywords:</td>
        <td class=""><input type="text" name="product_keywords" required></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="valign">Image:</td>
        <td class=""><input type="file" name="product_image" required></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="valign">Description:</td>
        <td class=""><textarea name="product_desc"></textarea></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="valign">Specifications:</td>
        <td class=""><textarea name="product_spec"></textarea></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="submit">
        <td></td>
        <td class="f-right"><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

  <?php

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $product_title     = $_POST['product_title'];
    $product_price     = $_POST['product_price'];
    $product_cat       = $_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_brand     = $_POST['product_brand'];
    $product_keywords  = $_POST['product_keywords'];
    $product_image     = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
    $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];
    $product_desc      = addslashes($_POST['product_desc']);
    $product_spec      = addslashes($_POST['product_spec']);

    move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp, "product_images/$product_image");

    $insert_products = "INSERT INTO products (product_cat, product_brand, product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_spec, product_image, product_keywords)
                            VALUES ('$product_cat', '$product_brand', '$product_title', '$product_price', '$product_desc', '$product_spec', '$product_image', '$product_keywords')";

    $run_products = mysqli_query($con, $insert_products);

    $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $run_products);
      echo "<script>alert('Product has been uploaded succesfully!')</script>";
      echo "<script>window.open('index.php?insert_product','_self')</script>";
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$run_products = mysqli_query($con, $insert_products);

$run_query = mysqli_query($con, $run_products);
  echo "<script>alert('Product has been uploaded succesfully!')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.open('index.php?insert_product','_self')</script>";
```

You are putting the function mysqli_query into another mysqli_query function. This will obviously not work as it tries to run a query consisting out of the results of the first query.

Replace it with:

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $insert_products)){
  echo "<script>alert('Product has been uploaded succesfully!')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.open('index.php?insert_product','_self')</script>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I dont't know why i did that way... now the error is gone, but the upload don't work either... The $con is correct, the database is correct... No error, but no upload :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$run_products = mysqli_query($con, $insert_products);
$run_query = mysqli_query($con, $run_products);
```

Why are you doing second mysqli_query and run in on results of first mysqli_query?

Right now you have error with seconds mysqli_query because now it is working on result of first mysqli_query. mysqli_query requires query not result of query

Answer (score -1):

OOOOoookkay... I find something. Somehow the img uploading is the problem. If I delete it from the INSERT line, everithing works fine...

Thank you for helping anyway :)